# Creating a Column-Vector in Python Numpy in Fortran order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fortran

I need a numpy array with 3-rows and 1 Column (for pyCGNS when creating a Zone).

And This Must be true when asking if it is `NPY.isfortran(X)`.

I tried several ways, but none worked.

e.g.

```
a1 = NPY.zeros((3,1),order='F')
print NPY.isfortran(a1) 
->False
```

Comment: If one of the dimensions is 1 then there is absolutely no difference between the C order and the Fortran Order. The elements are ordered as a 1D array would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyCGNS can not create a column vector.

I solved the problem by programming the CGNS header (base and zone) in C.

And then loaded the created file from the C program in pyCGNS and built upon it.

Answer (score 1):

The function is [obsolete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfortran.html). it  returns:

> True if the array is Fortran contiguous BUT not C contiguous.

```
In [421]: np.isfortran(a1)
Out[421]: False

In [422]: a1.flags
Out[422]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Your array is fortran contiguous AND C contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [`isfortran` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfortran.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns True if the array is Fortran contiguous **but not** C contiguous.
>
> This function is obsolete and, because of changes due to relaxed stride checking, its return value for the same array may differ for versions of NumPy >= 1.10.0 and previous versions. If you only want to check if an array is Fortran contiguous use `a.flags.f_contiguous` instead.

There are a few things to note here:

1. Your vector is both Fortran and C contiguous, so the function returns false.
2. The function is obsolete

There is an alternative way to check the array, that should work for your case:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 1), order='F')
print(a.flags)
# C_CONTIGUOUS : True
# F_CONTIGUOUS : True
# OWNDATA : True
# WRITEABLE : True
# ALIGNED : True
# UPDATEIFCOPY : False

print(a.flags.f_contiguous)
# True
```

You cannot edit flags. However, there are a few tricks. For example, you can use transpose to turn a 2D C array into an F array (albeit with swapped dimensions):

```
print(np.ones((3, 2), order='C').flags)
#  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
# ....

print(np.ones((3, 2), order='C').T.flags)
#  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
#  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
# ....
```

Comment: Is there a way to Modify the Numpy Array flags.

Comment: No, they are read only. This makes sense because they are *descriptive* not *presciptive*. If you want different flags you need to create a new array (or at least a new view).